# Cycle in database

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, entity-framework

during working on my project (angular 8 + asp.net 3.0) i received 500 error when trying to get all Products:

`"System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32."`

Where is my cycle? Maybe i should rebuild all my models? Can anybody explain me what I am doing wrong?
The idea was to create CRUD with Products which could be used to make Dishes from them. In future User will be able to add product or dish to his daily menu. Thanks for help.

my modelBuilder below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Dish)
                .WithMany(x => x.Ingredients)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.DishId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Product)
                .WithMany(x => x.Element)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.DishId, x.ProductId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Photo)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Dish>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Photo)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ9De.png)

Comment: "System.Text.Json.JsonException" The problem seems to be in serialization to json, not in EF.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to change configuration, models etc. Problem solved by adding this line. Thanks @bnu

`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);`